# How to use a specific reply-to address in Gmail based on sender

Tags: gmail

I have a single Gmail account where I forward multiple other accounts into. This  way I get a unified inbox.

I also have those other accounts set up so that I can send from each address. The last piece is that I even set up preferences so that I reply from the address that originally received the email.

This is all working fine. Except one thing.

On occasion, I get messages where the destination is a distribution list, and not one of my specific email addresses. This is the case for Google groups, too. This ends up causing Gmail to use my main email address as the reply-to… which isn't the right one for some of these groups.

Question: Is it possible to set up Gmail to use a specific `from:` address (one of my accounts) based on the sender or other rules?

Comment: Based on rules, I have no idea, I normally just switch what address I want displayed with the understanding, anyone who receives that emails, actually still knows what email address I used.

Comment: I don't use gmail, however use a similar setup elsewhere.  In my case there is a difference on selection of from address for replies based on whether the email was forwarded to that box (as you do) or collected from another mail system via POP/IMAP.  If gmail makes such a collection facility available, try it. You may find you don't even need the rules you already created.